# Is there any way to concatinate multiple video and audio streams with offset?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am sory for my english, it is not my mother language. My issue related to ffmpeg concatenation of audio and video streams. There are multiple audio and video streams which were recorded by online chat. All of them have start and end time points. If user turned off a micro or camera then audio and video streams wouldn't be matched. How can I align all streams in one time series? Can I add some white noise to separate the two videos? Similar with audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using seek `-ss` to (`-to` or `-t`) and the `concat` filter out can concatenate parts of multiple input files. Something like this:

```sh
# create three 10 second test input files with different sine tones
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc -f lavfi -i sine=400 -t 10 clip1.mp4
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc -f lavfi -i sine=600 -t 10 clip2.mp4
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc -f lavfi -i sine=800 -t 10 clip3.mp4
# create a separator file
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i nullsrc -f lavfi -i anoisesrc -t 1 noise.mp4

# concatenate parts of the clips with a separator in between
# -ss is seek to timestamp
# -to is stop at timestamp
# use concat filer to appends all the input files streams in the order 
# they are passed as input arguments
ffmpeg \
    -ss 00:01 -to 00:03 -i clip1.mp4 \
    -i noise.mp4 \
    -ss 00:04 -to 00:06 -i clip2.mp4 \
    -i noise.mp4 \
    -ss 00:07 -to 00:09 -i clip3.mp4 \
    -i noise.mp4 \
    -filter_complex \
    '[0:v][0:a] [1:v][1:a] [2:v][2:a] [3:v][3:a] [4:v][4:a]concat=n=5:v=1:a=1[v][a]' \
    -map '[v]' -map '[a]' \
    output.mp4
```

Hope that helps!